# How to launch the QMainwindow from QDialog after the interval selected by user on QDialog combobox using QTimer

Tags: pyqt5

I have a QMainWIndow called Main which calls QDialog called popup_on_waiver. QDialog has a combobox to select number of hours. Once user selects hours and clicks Ok, I want to close the popup, hide the QMainwindow and launch the QMainwindow after selected number of hours from combobox. Program works until user selects hours and cliks ok. It closes popup and hides main window.(Requirement is that app has to be running in hidden forever, so hiding the main window). When it calls launch_after_interval, its failing with error "Process finished with exit code 1073741845". Please advise on the correct steps.
I am launching the Main window on certain other conditions that are not provided below so I am writing a separate block for launching the main window again after waiver hours selected by the user. Also, I tried to fetch the result of popup window, accepted or rejected but it didnt return anything.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt, QTimer, QSize, QRect
import sys


class popup_on_waiver(QDialog):
    #pop up window
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(660, 340))
        self.setWindowTitle("Waiver")

        self.cb = QComboBox()   #combobox
        self.cb.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 100, 30))
        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4"])
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.returnInterval)
        self.cb.setObjectName("combobox")
        self.cb.move(80, 80)

        self.buttons = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.buttons.accepted.connect(self.hide_main)
        self.buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)  #buttons

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)   #layout
        vbox.addWidget(self.cb)
        vbox.addWidget(self.buttons)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


    def hide_main(self, hours):
        self.accept
        self.parent().hide()
        launch_after_interval(self.interval)  #calling timer function


    def returnInterval(self, hours):      #combobox value that is number of hours
        self.interval = int(hours) * 3600 * 1000

#QMainwindow
class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.Waiver = QPushButton('Waiver')
        self.Waiver.clicked.connect(lambda: self.popup())

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.Waiver)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Timesheet")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(""))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()

    def popup(self):
        self.p = popup_on_waiver()
        self.p.exec_()


def launch_after_interval(interval): 
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.setSingleShot(True)
    timer.setInterval(interval)
    timer.timeout().connect(lambda: Main())
    timer.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems with your code:

1. you create the dialog without setting the parent, so when you try to call `self.parent().hide()` it won't work because `parent()` returns `None`, which obviously doesn't have a `hide` attribute;
2. you have connected the `accepted` signal to `hide_main`, which requires an argument, but the [`accepted`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accepted) signal doesn't have any;
3. you missed the parentheses of `accepted` in `hide_main`, so it wouldn't be called;
4. `self.interval` is set only whenever the index of the combo is changed, but if the user doesn't change it (by leaving the default value), there won't be any `self.interval` set;
5. you are setting the `WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag **only**, which will reset any other window flags; the result will be that you won't have a new window, but a widget that is "embedded" in the parent; to correctly set the flag you should use `self.setWindowFlags(self.flags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`;
6. signals cannot be "called", so there should be no parentheses in `timer.timeout().connect`;
7. the `timer` object has no reference outside the scope of `launch_after_interval`, nor it has no parent object set, so it will be deleted as soon as the function returns and will never be fired;

Revised code (modifications are in bold):

```py
class popup_on_waiver(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(660, 340))
        self.setWindowTitle("Waiver")

        self.cb = QComboBox()   #combobox
        self.cb.setGeometry(QRect(40, 40, 100, 30))
        self.cb.addItems(["1", "2", "3", "4"])
        self.cb.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.returnInterval)
        self.cb.setObjectName("combobox")
        self.cb.move(80, 80)

        self.buttons = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel, Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.buttons.accepted.connect(self.hide_main)
        self.buttons.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.cb)
        vbox.addWidget(self.buttons)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        # set the default interval
        self.interval = 3600000


    # no arguments here!
    def hide_main(self):
        self.accept() # <-- the parentheses!
        self.parent().hide()
        launch_after_interval(self.interval)

    def returnInterval(self, hours):
        self.interval = int(hours) * 3600 * 1000

class Main(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.Waiver = QPushButton('Waiver')
        # if the function does not have arguments, lambda is usually not required
        self.Waiver.clicked.connect(self.popup)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.Waiver)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Timesheet")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(""))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.show()

    def popup(self):
        # the parent is required to make the dialog modal *and* allow it
        # to call parent().hide()!
        self.p = popup_on_waiver(self)
        self.p.exec_()


def launch_after_interval(interval):
    # set a parent QObject for the timer, so that it's not removed
    # when the function returns
    timer = QTimer(QApplication.instance())
    timer.setSingleShot(True)
    timer.setInterval(interval)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: Main())
    timer.start()
```

Other *relatively* minor issues:

- similar attribute names (like `centralwidget`, which is *too* similar to QMainWindow's `centralWidget()`) should be avoided, as they can create confusion and lead to hard to find bugs and issues;
- a timer that acts on an object should not be created outside of the object that will eventually call/access/show it (even if indirectly); while technically there's nothing wrong with it, it's usually better to keep objects "organized", so that they can be accessed if required (for example, showing the window and stopping the timer before it times out);
- creating a new instance of the main window is not suggested, as one already exists; this is related to the previous point: if you have a direct reference to the timer *and* the window, you can also call `self.someWindow.show()`;
- avoid mixing and confusing naming styles: you've used upper case names for attributes (`Waiver`) and lower for classes (`popup_on_waiver`), while it should be the opposite; then there's also mixedCase (`returnInterval`) and under_score (`hide_main`); choose a style and keep that one (read more about it in the [style guide for Python code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), aka PEP-8);

I preferred to edit only the parts of your code that prevented the program to work, but you should really keep the aspects above in mind, even if they are "relatively minor" (emphasis on *relatively*).

Finally, (trivial, but not irrelevant): mixing import modes from the same modules should be avoided: you either use wildcard imports like `from module import *` (but you normally [shouldn't](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)) or explicit ones like `from module import ClassA, ClassB, [...]`; for big modules like PyQt5, it's common to import the submodule, like `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets`:

Good:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class SomeWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...
```

Also good, but tends to be very obnoxious as you have to remember to add classes each time you need a new one and you might end up with a really long list of imports, possibly resulting in unnecessary classes as you ended up in not using some (also, I doubt there's a substantial benefit, at least on Qt):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout # etc...

class SomeWidget(QWidget):
    # ...
```

Not so good, but it works (keeping submodule names can be useful to keep also in mind their "scope") and behaves as the previous one:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

And this, this is simply *wrong* (I mean, it works, but it doesn't make any sense):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
```

Comment: Much thanks for the detailed response. It works as expected. Thanks.